# route undefined in google maps api while finding the duration between two places

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i am using google maps api in java script. i want to find the duration between two locations. but i got error as route undefined. here i am define as

```
 farevalue =gm.directions.route(booking_count.booking_from,booking_count.destination_to,function(err,result){
        console.log(data.socket_session_id);

        durtion = result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
        km = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
        distance =result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;        
}
```

Comment: What is gm.directions? How is it created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i found the answer for my question. I didn't give the array index for my array. so it takes undefined value for addresses.
The routes simplified syntax is routes(starting point address, ending point address , callback function). In callback function we can find the distance and duration. Make sure that the addresses are correctly initialized.